# Debian, Xfce: Volumes mounted by Thunar unmounted after suspend, "file exists" when trying to mount them again with Thunar

Tags: debian, mount, xfce, thunar

I've just reinstalled my Linux desktop, and now have a problem that I haven't experienced on Ubuntu Xfce:

If I mount a volume, suspend the computer and then wake it up, volumes that were mounted before the suspend are unmounted. The mount points for the volumes however are still there, which results in a "file exists" error when trying to mount the volumes again with Thunar.

Wanted behaviour would be that they're either mounted again after wake from suspend, or that they're properly unmounted on suspend (mount points deleted).

**What can I do to make this work in a better way?**

Comment: This looks like a bug. Now pinpointing the location of the bug isn't that easy. Thunar probably relies on a privileged helper to do the mount. So what creates the directory, what mounts it and what actually fails because of the suspend? Complex topic. Is the volume a local disk or a network resource?  Here on Debian 12 XFCE, Thunar doesn't behave as you describe when mounting an USB stick and suspending the system: the mount is still ok after. You should provide enough information so your bug is reproducible. And then if it's a bug, reporting the bug to Debian might be an idea.

Comment: @A.B, good point. Thanks for your input! I'll check if it might have anything to do with that the volumes are BTRFS too.